# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.linalg.basic

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have tried to create an executable file using the pyinstaller library for a Python code that generates a user interface. The code uses different libraries, including cvxpy, numpy, and matplotlib. Once the executable is created, when I run it, I get the following error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.linalg.basic'".

I have already updated scipy and the problem persists. I appreciate your help in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have SciPy correctly installed with this command: `pip show scipy`

If you have it, can you try `pyinstaller --hidden-import scipy.linalg.basic <your-script-name>.py` and afterward `pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import scipy.linalg.basic <your-script-name>.py` on your bash?

Also, the `scipy.linalg` documentation can help https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.html. I didn't see `scipy.linalg.basic` in that documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After uninstall and install scipy again, the .exe file is running as spected